# Can't find a way to enter BIOS settings!

Tags: boot, grub2, keyboard, bios

I am trying to enter BIOS settings on my Lenovo Desktop PC, but I can't figure out how to do it! I have entered it before, because I had to enable Intel Virtualization Technology, but I don't remember it to be so hard as it is now. I have tried to use the keys that is specified for my machine on Lenovos pages, but it won't work. When I try to press for example F1 repeatedly, I just enter grub menu, which I don't normally do on regular bootups.

As well as this, when the grub menu pops up, I am not able to use my keyboard to navigate here, and I don't know if this have something to do with this.

My system is a Lenovo ThinkCentre Edge 72, running Ubuntu 18.04, in case that helps.

Comment: It is not the all in one version

Comment: add a usb keyboard and try again

Comment: I will try these things, and then come back :1

Comment: It turns out I did the correct keys and all that stuff, it was just an issue with the keyboard (that I have no idea what is), so when I plugged in a different keyboard, F1 worked.

Comment: wow, thats good, I never saw a problem like that, I had problems to enter on bios for many reasons, but never needed to use a usb keyboard, very good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page 73 of the [User Guide for the ThinkCentre Edge 72 Desktop](https://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/thinkcentre_pdf/edge72_tower_ug_en.pdf)  specifies <kbd>F1</kbd> is the key to use to get into the BIOS/Firmware Setup. It says to press that key **repeatedly**. The BIOS/Firmware setup comes before the bootloader which comes before the rest of the OS, so this is well before the OS starts.

If you can't get the PC to recognize your pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> then try another keyboard.

Comment: But I have tried to press F1, but I just keep entering grub menu instead :(

Comment: Does this have something to do with the OS?

Comment: No. The BIOS/Firmware setup comes before the bootloader which comes before the rest of the OS.

Comment: Ok. Do you think it have something to do with the keyboard? When I enter grub menu, the keyboard can't do anything.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Last time I used BIOS settings, I proably used my other keyboard, but I didn't remember that. If anyone know why one of my keyboards worked, but not the other, I would appreciate to hear the answer.